# How to give 777 permission to multiple directories at a time in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have several sub directories in a root directory. at a time i want to give `chmod 777` permission to those directories.

i know individually we can give `chmod -r 777 abcd` but i want to give permission to those directories which ever i require at a time.

Example :

```
XYZ -- Parent Directory 

ABCD EGF GHY JHF OIEDF -- These are sub directories.

now i want to give chmod 777 to ABCD EGF GHY . at a time to all these directories.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To the directories and also the files inside? If so, you can use the `-R -->
              change files and directories recursively`

Comment: `chmod 777 ABCD EGF GHY`??

Answer (score 15):

Assuming XYZ is the path to the root of your files, you can use globbing to exactly match the files you want:

```
chmod 777 /XYZ/{ABCD,EGF,GHY}
```

Then you can use the `-R` flag to do it recursively on all files and folders contained in these folders.

```
chmod -R 777 /XYZ/{ABCD,EGF,GHY}
```

To apply a non-recursive chmod on the 3 folder plus the parent, you can use:

```
chmod 777 /XYZ/{ABCD,EGF,GHY,}
```

Note the last comma, to include the directory itself in the globbing

Comment: chmod: cannot access `/XYZ/ABCD': No such file or directory

Comment: From my post: " Assuming XYZ is the path to the root of your files,". Change XYZ to the actual path to your files, or use a relative path (without the leading / )

Comment: chmod 777 /Marin/{TMS,TDA,TDA_AD_AD,TMS_AD_ID} i gave like this, any wrong in this. please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I really doubt that you've got a folder named Marin at the root of you file system. Did you mean `/home/Marin` ?

Comment: When you're in the parent folder, to know its location (path), just type `pwd` and use this value. When you type `../` in a path name, then it's a relative path, `..` referring to the parent folder

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the same directory as the files/directories whose permissions you want to change, you can run the code below.

```
chmod -R 777 {ABCD, EGF, GHY, JHF, OIEDF}
```